# How to measure the battery voltage in a TTGO T18?

Tags: esp8266, esp32

I am using a TTGO T18 to monitor temperature using deep sleep (ESP32.) I would also like to measure the battery voltage and publish to MQTT, but I am unable to find the ADC pin or the battery measurement circuit in the schematic. As per Andreas Spiess (youtube), this board has the feature.

Attached is a screen shot of his confirmation. Any help or pointers will be highly helpful.

[image: TTGO]

[Schematic Of TTGO T18](https://github.com/LilyGO/LILYGO-T-Energy/blob/master/t18_v3.0.pdf)

Comment: The schematc shows the battery voltage to be connected to GPIO35 (ADC1_CH7) through a voltage divider (1/2 of the actual battery voltage).

Comment: Thank you so much @StarCat, stupid of me.

Answer (score 1):

The ADC is on pin 35.

Here is the code that works for me to read the battery voltage:

```
// Battery is connected to GPIO 35 (Analog ADC1_CH6)
//const int batPin = 35;
#define PIN_ADC_BAT 35
#define ADC_BATTERY_LEVEL_SAMPLES 50
void read_adc_bat(uint16_t *voltage);
uint16_t v_bat = 0;

void read_adc_bat(uint16_t *voltage)
{
  uint32_t in = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < ADC_BATTERY_LEVEL_SAMPLES; i++)
  {
    in += (uint32_t)analogRead(PIN_ADC_BAT);
  }
  in = (int)in / ADC_BATTERY_LEVEL_SAMPLES;
  uint16_t bat_mv = ((float)in / 4096) * 3600 * 2;
  *voltage = bat_mv;
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(PIN_ADC_BAT, INPUT);
  read_adc_bat(&v_bat);
  Serial.print("BAT: ");
  Serial.println(v_bat);
}
```